# How to get most quickly 64-bit integer hash from 50 chars long string in PHP7?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, php-7, crc32

I have a MySQL MEMORY table in which I store key-value style data. Keys have usually 30-50 chars length. And therefore I want to shorten them so they don't take too precious RAM space (there will be 10 - 100k+ such key-values in DB).

Right now I am thinking about using CRC32 checksum as hash, which is 32bit integer and so I can use int(10) type for column in MySQL database. But I am little worried about possible collisions when dealing with 100k+ hashes, probability rises very quickly when having so many different keys.

So I would like to use 64bit hash, where collisions should be only theoretical problem, I think. And it would take only bigint(20) type for MySQL column (still saving a lot of RAM space). But I couldn't find any reasonable quick algorithm as CRC32 which is one order of magnitude faster than all other functions. Below is quick benchmark results (100 000 iterations each):

```
crc32:  0.0074591636657715s     798740135
sha64:  0.067406177520752s      4718257680194979118
crc64:  0.037574052810669s      989304075990411149
md5:    0.02372s                0dbab6d0c841278d33be207f14eeab8b
sha1:   0.03382s                417a9e5c9ac7c52e32727cfd25da99eca9339a80
xor:    0.07939s                119
xor2:   0.06522s                134217728
add:    0.0665s                 1105
```

As I don't need any "crypto-secure" solution, only the fastest way how to get 64-bit number from 50 characters long string. Thank you very much for any idea. I am targeting PHP7+ environment.

Comment: CRC32 has ~1% collision chance per 10k. If you'd use 2 CRC32 per key (one per half of the key for instance, or taking every other char for CRC1, the other for CRC2), and if keys characters distribution is ~homogeneous, you'd have a ~0.01% collision chance per 10k. Not reliable. If you need a collision probability so low that it's negligible (sha256...), better keep the keys! Anyway, are you so memory low? ~40 chars per key x 100k max is 4MB!